# WPF Buttons with Paths as Content

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I ran into an interesting thing and I can't figure out how to fix it at the moment, maybe I'm missing something really simple.

I'm re-designing some of the UI but I'm not really experienced with it right now.
So I have 3 buttons and I wanted to draw patterns as the content of the buttons instead of using images.

I have managed to do so(still needs tweaking), but the buttons on hover event only triggers once my pointer enters the pattern area instead of the area of the button. Does anyone mind taking a look at it please?

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Width="35" Height="35" 
        Command="{StaticResource MinimizeCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
        Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <Path Data="M20,14H4V10H20" VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="2.6"
          Margin="7,20,7,10" Stretch="Fill" Width="16">
         <Path.Fill>
             <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource MainForeColor}"/>
         </Path.Fill>
    </Path>
</Button>
```

Code : https://hastebin.com/kofaqehoti.xml

Comment: Perhaps you need to approach "PointerOver" instead.  You will have to get into the visual states and storyboard for button behavior to be similar to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the background and the border brushes of the buttons to null the button will only be clickable and detectable for hover where the paths are drawn. Replace the nulls with Transparent or `#00000000` and the buttons will be invisible but clickable/hoverable (If that's a word)

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Width="35" Height="35" 
        Command="{StaticResource MinimizeCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
        Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#00000000">
    <Path Data="M20,14H4V10H20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="2.6" Margin="7,20,7,10" Stretch="Fill" Width="16">
         <Path.Fill>
             <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource MainForeColor}"/>
         </Path.Fill>
    </Path>
</Button>
```